# How to detect window resize event using ResizeObserver

Tags: javascript, resize-observer

I'd like to detect widnow resize event using [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

currenlty I use

```
window.addEventListener('resize',() => console.log('resize'));
```

I want to refactor it and use ResizeObserver. Is it possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can observe `document.body`.

```js
new ResizeObserver(() => {
  console.log('resized')
}).observe(document.body)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think that ResizeObserver has better performance then simple window.addEventListener('resize',() => console.log('resize')); ?

Comment: My opinion is that this method does not have better performance.

Comment: This only gets triggered if you resize the window's width. Resizing the window's height doesn't change the size of the body hence this event never gets triggered.

Comment: @neojp does `window.addEventListener('resize')` get triggered when height changes?

Comment: @programmerRaj Yes, of course.

Comment: @neojp Is it a bug with `ResizeObserver` or is `ResizeObjserver` supposed to ignore changes to the window height?

Comment: It's not a bug, because your code is observing the body. The body won't change its height based on the window's height.

Comment: So I'm guessing you could set the `height` style to `100%` for `<body>` and it will observe

Comment: The callback parameter's rects do not account for scrollbars when listening to the body (or even the `<html>` element, I tried that too).